# MySQL InnoDB Plugin default engine type not accepting config setting

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a strange MySQL InnoDB issue that I've been struggling with for a few hours now. I'm asking this here, and also on the DBA StackExchange - I will cross-post the answer to the other site when answered.

I have enabled the InnoDB plugin as a replacement for the built-in version, and setting the `innodb_file_format` and `innodb_file_per_table` are not having the required effect. The MySQL status variables still show `Anaconda` as the default engine.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received!

***Relevant section of my.cnf settings***

The settings below do not exist elsewhere in the config overriding these options.

```
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_file_format      = Barracuda
innodb_strict_mode      = 1
```

***Relevant entries in SHOW VARIABLES***

This is how I know that Barracuda is available

```
| innodb_file_format              | Antelope               |
| innodb_file_format_check        | Barracuda              |
| innodb_file_per_table           | OFF                    |
| innodb_strict_mode              | OFF                    |
| innodb_version                  | 1.0.9                  |
```

***Section of MySQL Log***

The log is also showing that Barracuda is available...

```
111020 18:10:13 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /.../mysql_data/
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
111020 18:10:13  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
111020 18:10:13 InnoDB Plugin 1.0.9 started; log sequence number 5609019
111020 18:10:13 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
111020 18:10:13 [Note] /.../mysql/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.48-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the answer, and it was [unsurprisingly] staring me in the face the whole time...

I had inherited the system from an earlier admin, who had made a mistake in the `my.cnf` file putting all the InnoDB specific parameters under a [innodb] heading, instead of under the [mysqld] heading where it should be.

Why did this take so long to locate? It was assumed that the config was working correctly in the first place. [slaps head]...

**Incorrect file segment**

```
[mysqld]
# Stuff here

[innodb]
# innodb stuff here
```

**Correct file segment**

```
[mysqld]
# Stuff here

# innodb stuff here
```

And now everything works as intended.